# How to specify the number of messages to be retrieved in Java Mail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I need to retrieve only a specific number of messages from a certain folder. Here is my code so far which retrieves all the messages.

```
        Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
        store.connect();
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED), false));
        inbox.close(false);
        store.close();
```

Although it is possible using `inbox.getMessages(start, end)`, this would retrieve all the messages where as I want to retrieve only the filtered/searched messages.

Is there a way to specify limit/page size in javax.mail library which I may have missed?